# Minimum overlap for symmetrical co-occurrence matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I have an asymmetrical occurrence matrix

```
OC <- matrix(c(2,0,2,
               1,1,0,
               0,3,3,
               0,2,2,
               0,0,1), 
             nrow=5, ncol=3, byrow = TRUE)
```

and I transform this matrix into a symmetrical co-occurrence matrix based on the multiplication over the columns:

```
t(OC)%*%OC
```

However, I was trying to find the symmetrical co-occurrence matrix, but using the minimum overlap. I am trying to apply the proposition of Morris (2005) for a bibliometric study. The results should be:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    3    1    2
[2,]    1    6    5
[3,]    2    5    8
```

I don't know how to identify the minimum shortest path to estimate this matrix. Any help would be highly appreciated!

Reference: 
Morris, S.A. (2005). Unified Mathematical Treatment of Complex Cascaded Bipartite Networks: The Case of Collections of Journal Papers. Unpublished PhD Thesis, Oklahoma State University. Retrieved from http://digital.library.okstate.edu/etd/umi-okstate-1334.pdf